# OrchardCore Localization in Asp.Net Core - AddViewLocalization error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, orchardcms

I am trying to insert the localization using PO file. My project is on Asp.Net core and uses Orchard core.

I am following this guide - [Configure Portable Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but I have a problem with the initial registration of the localization.

I should add the following code:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
```

Technically, my project should have `service.AddMvc()` by default, but I am using `services.AddOrchardCms()` instead.
When I try to call the first code to register the localization:

```
...
services.AddOrchardCms();
services.AddMvc()..AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
...
```

I receive an error as the application "Can not find the index page" (It actually does not exist as I am using `services.AddOrchardCms()` and I think they have a conflict).

And, of course, if I don't insert the `AddViewLocalization()` the PO files don't work.
Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Ever get this working and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

AddOrchardCms is internally calling AddMvc, by calling it again you are overwriting Orchard pipline with basic MVC pipeline. Try calling:

```
services
   .AddOrchardCms()
   .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
```

instead.